# What is the deal with offline_access? Is it still in use?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, offline, access-token

I can request an access_token upon supplying an `offline_access` scope parameter to oauth. I can execute OpenGraph commands that require an access_token just fine when logged out of Facebook, and when I log back in, I don't need to create a new one.

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) blog post, offline_access is (getting?) deprecated.

Confusions:

- Why doesn't the authentication dialog display that I am requesting offline access when authenticating a user?
- Is it currently safe to rely on persistent access_tokens?

Clarification greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow. Facebook development freaking sucks.  They seriously break crap all the time.  I don't know why us developers put up with this.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API generally shouldn't be accessed when the user isn't online. You can update the access token anyways, and that should be good enough.

Comment: My app does analysis on a user's post, in particular it counts the amount of likes posts submitted through the api have. To do so, I was thinking of running a cron job, and I cannot depend on the user being online.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/

> There are no changes required for most apps, but developers utilizing
>   the 'offline_access' permission will have until May 1, 2012 to update
>   their apps.

You have some time....